# Koa middleware type definitions requires a Middleware member export

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, koa2

I'm using koa with Typescript. I also use the koa middleware koa-static and koa-bodyparser. I have the type definition packages `@types/koa`, `@types/koa-bodyparser` and `@types/koa-static` installed. When I run `tsc` I get the following errors:

`ERROR in [default] ./node_modules/@types/koa-bodyparser/index.d.ts:69:8 
Namespace 'Koa' has no exported member 'Middleware'.`

and

`ERROR in [default] ./node_modules/@types/koa-static/index.d.ts:45:8 
Namespace 'Koa' has no exported member 'Middleware'.`

I doubt this error has anything to do with my own code. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I found this merged pull request https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/13447. This had me check my current installed type definitions. I found that the current version of `@types/koa` (0.0.0) does not yet export the required Middleware member that the newer versions of `@types/koa-bodyparser` (3.0.23) and `@types/koa-static` (2.0.22) is looking for. Revert their versions back to `3.0.20` and `2.0.21` respectively.